# How to make this list in SwiftUI scrollable

Tags: list, swiftui, .searchable

Edit: The scrolling works outside of the text.

Now I am making my first project. I can´t seem to fix this code. It won't scroll.

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct SøkView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(search(texts: texts, for: searchText), id: \.self) {
                    text in
                    Text(text)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button {
                            UIPasteboard.general.string = text
                        }
                        label: {
                            Text("Copy")
                            Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
                        }
                    }
                    .onLongPressGesture {
                        // Handle long press here, maybe show a custom menu
                        // or perform additional actions
                        print("Long pressed on \(text)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("Observations")
        }
    }

    func search(texts: [String], for searchText: String) -> [String] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return texts
        } else {
            return texts.filter {
                $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no issues with the scrolling, make sure you are not using the `selectable` preview

Comment: `id: \.self` is an obvious mistake (you must use a real id) but it might not cause the scroll problem